# String compare in C# with LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to resolve the issue with string compare in c# but unfortunately, it is not working

```
Expression<Func<Physician, bool>> PredicateLicense = x => x.LicenseNumber == LicenseNumber;
```

this is what I have done

```
Expression<Func<Physician, bool>> PredicateLicense = string.Compare(x => x.LicenseNumber,LicenseNumber,true);
```

but the above line throws an exception. how can I do that?

Comment: "but the above line throws an exception" - what exception? It looks like it shouldn't compile, which is somewhat different... What about the first line you've got instead?

Comment: (It's hard to see how this could *possibly* be relevant to C# 2.0 given that that didn't even support lambda expressions. If you're not asking about something specific to individual C# versions, please don't use the versioned tags - just `c#` is fine. There's also nothing about ASP.NET MVC in your question at the moment, so I question how useful that tag is...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant that the code is not compiling and not throwing an exception?

You didn't specify why you want to use `string.Compare` but I assume that you want to ignore the case when comparing the license number.

If this is the case I would advise you to:

```
Expression<Func<Physician, bool>> predicateLicense = 
    p => p.LicenseNumber.Equals(licenseNumber, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Regarding the `Compare` method, note that it returns `int` and not `bool` so you might do:

```
Expression<Func<Physician, int>> predicateLicense =
    p => string.Compare(p.LicenseNumber, licenseNumber, true);
```

For more info about Compare method and its return value meanings, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0#returns).